# PHP - Can't start session suddenly on GoDaddy website

Tags: php

I had a perfectly functional GoDaddy website (under development) before Christmas break.  It has not been changed.  Today, I logged on and I have all these strange errors regarding sessions that weren't there before.

To investigate, I made a new file and threw it on the site with the contents:

```
<?PHP
    session_start();
    echo "HELLO WORLD!";
?>
```

Navigating to this page in a freshly opened browser gives the following output:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/chroot/home/content/05/8547705/tmp/sess_m3uikb1qe6v5hsjir8ilsfa811, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/content/05/8547705/html/try.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/05/8547705/html/try.php:2) in /home/content/05/8547705/html/try.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/05/8547705/html/try.php:2) in /home/content/05/8547705/html/try.php on line 2
HELLO WORLD!
Warning: Unknown: open(/var/chroot/home/content/05/8547705/tmp/sess_m3uikb1qe6v5hsjir8ilsfa811, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct () in Unknown on line 0
```

I don't even know where to start with this - does anyone know what could have changed to make this basic file not work?

Comment: This seems like a mistake on GoDaddy's part. Contact their customer support.

Comment: This seems to be a server issue. Perhaps a move to http://www.serverfault.com is in order?

Comment: Recommendation: Get off GoDaddy (if possible), they don't have the best hosting. (I'd make a recommendation for a hosting provider but that wouldn't be appropriate here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't seen the first warning, but the others happen if the script sends headers or data before the call to session_start().  You can fix that by either:

1) making sure that there's no HTML or whitespace before session_start(), or,
2) using output buffering (see ob_start() and ob_end_flush().

With (2) you can start the session anytime during script execution; the buffering makes sure headers and response data are sent to the browser in the right order.

Comment: The 'headers already sent' warnings are simply byproducts of the first warning. After the `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/c...` message has been displayed, __clearly__ the headers have already been sent.

Comment: Looks like godaddy got rid of the folder where PHP stores its sessions, or changed the permissions.  As others have mentioned, contact support.  You could also set an alternate sessions folder using session_save_path() but it would be better if they fixed their configuration issue.

Comment: I used session_save_path() to mitigate the errors and got in touch with GoDaddy to have them fix them (hopefully :/).  Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of any white space before session_start()

Comment: Why this should help? If the file is really the one posted, the whitespaces before the line 2 don't matter because they are inside the <?php tag.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: Actually, that could help. If there was an invisible character such as a BOM in the beginning of the file (before opening PHP), this could cause a 'headers already sent' error. This is, however, not the case here. That error is just a byproduct of the first error regarding insufficient access to a temp folder.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but there's no white space and the files I have on the real website didn't used to do this, so I figure its somehow configuration related but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: No problem. Then I think it's a hosting/permissions problem. try calling godaddy. Or better yet, change hosting providers ;)

Comment: @KristianAntonsen Infact, as I said, the whitespaces **before** the line 2 don't matter if they're **inside**  the <?php tag.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is very old, but maybe this will help someone.
I was getting the same type session errors. The session path in the errmsg did not exist. Yet, the session path in the CPanel configuration existed.
If you've had a old website at godaddy that's been migrated or updated to CPanel, you may have an old .user.ini file that is incorrectly setting the path for session that will conflict/override the one you can specify in CPanel.
Suggest commenting out the one in .user.ini and using the one in Cpanel.
The problem can also happen when you change versions of PHP as the session save path may have the php version in it. That is why you want to use the one in CPanel.
Probably good idea to examine the other settings in .user.ini and remove ones that are no longer necessary/can be set in CP.